# Why are transforms typically passed when working with in-game objects rather than game objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am well along in learning Unity basics but would like to nail down my understanding of the relation between components and the objects that own them.  In the tutorials I've been watching typically use or pass the Transform component when working with objects pulled in code. For example:

```
void Explode ()
{
    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, explosionRadius);
    foreach (Collider collider in colliders)
    {
        if (collider.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            Damage(collider.transform);
        }
    }
}
```

which calls "Damage" with the transform on the colliders it finds:

```
void Damage (Transform enemy)
{
    Enemy e = enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>();
    if (e != null)
    {
        e.TakeDamage(damage);
    }
}
```

Looking at this, it is clear that it is pulling a Component found on all game objects and then using "GetComponent" to pull another component instance by name since the "Enemy" component isn't going to have its own method. Why not just pass collider.gameObject though?  I tried this (after changing the Damage to expect a GameObject) and it worked fine.

This seems more intuitive to me but all of the tutorials I've seen use the transform component instead. Does anyone have any insight into why this is so? It would help me deepen my understanding of how Unity structures its code.

Comment: Maybe all the tutorials you watched are copied from one ancestor

Comment: personally I would actually try to `GetComponent<Enemy>()` fist and than call the method passing the reference to `Enemy` instead ;)

Comment: That makes sense to me derHugo.  And Shingo, I've been watching the tutorials from Brackeys and some from Unity itself.  It seemed like a pattern that was developing so I thought I'd ask the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

GameObject is more intuitive as you say.

**Long answer**

I think (my opinion) it's best to pass the most specific and relevant component.

For example, assume you have a function for a character to pick up a crate:

```
public void PickUp(Transform crate)
{
    crate.SetParent(this.transform);
    crate.localPosition = Vector3.zero; // or whatever your attachment point is
}
```

Here it makes sense in my mind that the Transform is passed, because it's the most specific component that will be needed.By passing GameObject here you are only delaying the inevitable `GetComponent<Transform>` or `go.transform`.

On the other hand, if you have a function to hide a create then passing the game object would be the bare minimum you need to achieve this:

```
public void Hide(GameObject crate)
{
    crate.SetActive(false);
}
```

Passing anything else just delays the inevitable `x.gameObject`

In the explosion example I don't think that I would pass either to be honest. I would probably do this:

```
void Explode ()
{
    Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, explosionRadius);

    var enemies = colliders
                 .Select(x => x.GetComponent<Enemy>())
                 .OfType<Enemy>(); // Or IHealth, IDamageable, ITarget, etc if you have other things that can take damage.

    foreach (var enemy in enemies) // If empty, nothing will happen by default
    {
       enemy.TakeDamage(damage);
    }
}
```

With this approach you can see that there is no need to check tags or nulls. The enemies enumerable is guaranteed to contain either enemies or nothing at all.

By always passing gameObject/transforms you will always have to worry about what it is that you are really receiving at the destination component. You will also open yourself to situations where you are not sure anymore where certain changes to you gameObjects are being made because it can be anything in the system that's making those changes. Your `ColorChangerComponent` could actually also be moving the object around, destroying some other components, etc. By giving the component a Renderer, it more naturally limits the component to changes on the Renderer only (although you could obviously violate this limitation unless you perform actions against appropriate interfaces).

The only time it really makes sense to pass a generic component is when you are broadcasting this 'event' to a bunch of possible receivers that will each to a different thing with the object. I.e. you can't be certain at compile time what the gameobject will be used for, or you know that it will be used for many different things.

The fact that Unity itself returns `Collider[]` for the collision check sort of supports this line of thinking, otherwise it would've just returns `GameObject[]`. The same goes for `OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)` or `OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)` etc.

Comment: You should then have `using System.Linq;` on top of your script ;)

Comment: Thank you for the extended discussion.  This is exactly the kind of perspective that I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what tutorials you are following, but the ones I followed when I first started with Unity used GameObject instead of Transform.

I agree that it is more intuitive to use GameObject. Transform is a part or `Component` of a GameObject, but since it's mandatory it will always be there, hence the public field `.transform`. But since a GameObject is technically the holder of all its Componenents, it would be most logical, architecture wise, to pass that as a parameter instead.

At the end of the day, it makes little difference in your examples since you can call a lot of the same methods on both Transform as GameObject.

TLDR:

Use whatever you feel makes most sense.

Comment: Thank you!  This helps a lot.